How can I use L from Nuxt Leaflet module?
I am trying to incorporate a leaflet map to my Nuxt 3 project. I use Nuxt Leaflet module which works fine until I tried to directly use the L object from the leaflet library. I followed the docs.
My component is wrapped in ClientOnly component:
<ClientOnly fallback-tag="span" fallback="Loading venues ...">
  <VenuesMapCluster :venues="data.venues" />
</ClientOnly>

The venue-map-cluster.vue:
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script setup>

import L from 'leaflet'

...

</script>

However, this throws the following error:
The requested module 'http://localhost:3000/_nuxt/node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js?v=c19b9ad2' doesn't provide an export named: 'default'

These are my dependencies in the package.json file:
"dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/fonts": "^0.7.1",
    "@nuxt/icon": "^1.0.0",
    "@nuxt/ui": "^2.17.0",
    "@nuxtjs/leaflet": "^1.0.14",
    "knex": "^3.1.0",
    "leaflet.markercluster": "^1.5.3",
    "nuxt": "^3.12.3",
    "objection": "^3.1.4",
    "pg": "^8.12.0",
    "vue": "latest"
  }

How can I successfully load and use the L object from leaflet in Nuxt 3?

I'm testing the exact same configuration as in the docs https://leaflet.nuxtjs.org/guide/using-l.html and it's working no problem, if you copy-paste this example in your project does this work?
